# Angular date formatting from model

Tags: angularjs

I have an input that gets a datetime object from an `ng-model` and displays it. For whatever reason, I simply cannot get the date formatted correctly. However, when I check the code, the date is formatted. Can someone please explain?

Look at the `input value` versus what is actually displayed
[image]

Code:

```
      <div class="input-field col l4">
        <input value="{{note.contactHistoryNoteDate | date:'MMMM dd, yyyy'}}" ng-model="note.contactHistoryNoteDate" id="contactHistoryNoteDate1{{$index}}" type="text" class="datepicker edit-date">
        <label class="active" for="contactHistoryNoteDate1{{$index}}">DATE</label>
      </div>
```

Comment: You cannot use filters on an input field. You could create a watcher that formats the value using the filter in your directive though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value attribute is the initial value, the `ng-model` attribute binds the value to a model. What you are seeing is the bound value from `ng-model`.

Bonus:
To get the date to display as you want, you will need to create ([or find](https://github.com/eight04/angular-datetime)) a custom directive which will user angular's [parsers](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$parsers) and [formatters](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$formatters) pipelines. This pipelines are responsible for turning the user's input (what the user sees) into a value the code can use and vice-versa such as your case, turning a date into something the user can see/make more sense of.